# Processing 3, drawing resizing

Tags: java, processing, processing.js

I am currently creating a first person, starfield-like atmosphere on Processing 3 and need help in resizing a UFO-like object to appear on the screen, resize itself to get bigger and bigger on the screen (as if it is flying towards you), and disappear at a certain size. I was able to create the starfield (it is too much code for this question), however I could use some guidance as to how to make this UFO drew below to fly at you from a first person view, and disappear. I pasted my code for the UFO below.

```
void setup() {
size(400,400);
}

void draw() {
fill(30);
ellipse(200,65,100,50);
fill(20);
ellipse(200,50,75,40);
fill(100);
ellipse(200,40,40,30);
}
```

Note: If the size I created in the window it too small feel free to edit the code and repost with the new size, please just point where you changed.
2nd Note: I am a beginner coder and new to this forum so please don't judge me too hard

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your variables over time. Processing makes this pretty easy by calling the `draw()` function for you 60 times per second.

**Step 1:** Define your variables at the top of your sketch. If all you're changing is the ufo's vertical position, maybe all you care about is a `y` variable. But you might also make the ufo become bigger as it gets closer, in which case you'd want to also keep track of a `size` variable or something.

**Step 2:** Use those variables to draw your ufo. Right now you're hardcoding your ufo with numbers, but you need to use variables instead.

**Step 3:** Change those variables over time. You can change them every time `draw()` is called, which happens 60 times per second.

Here's a simple example that does all of the above to show a circle falling off the screen:

```
float y = 0;

void setup() {
  size(100, 300);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(width/2, y, 100, 100);
  y++;
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on animation in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).